# Unable to connect to remote MySQL database with mysql package

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have tried to connect to my remote MySQL database server with ***npm's mysql package*** but it keeps on throwing this error

But it works fine when I use **mysqli** with PHP

**ERROR:**

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/rilla/Desktop/dbTest/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:409:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:416:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:479:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/rilla/Desktop/dbTest/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/rilla/Desktop/dbTest/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/rilla/Desktop/dbTest/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/rilla/Desktop/dbTest/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rilla/Desktop/dbTest/test.js:22:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

**MY CODE:**

```
  // Get the mysql service
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    
    // Add the credentials to access your database
    // var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    //  host: "my_host", // hosts IP here
    //  port: 3306,
    //  user: "my_username",
    //  password: "my_password",
    //  database: "my_database",
    // });
    
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 100,
      host: "my_host", // hosts IP here
      port: 3306,
      user: "my_username",
      password: "my_password",
      database: "my_database",
    });
    
    pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('it works now')
      }
    });
    
    // connect to mysql
    // connection.connect(function (err) {
    //   // in case of error
    //   if (err) {
    //     console.log(err);
    //     console.log(err.code);
    //     console.log(err.fatal);
    //   } else {
    //     console.log('it works now')
    //   }
    // });
```

I have tried with **sequelize** too but no avail. I can't figure why it's not connecting

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Comment: Yeah am using mariaDB